# Не обновляется содержание базы данных

Tags: php, wordpress

Я создаю страницу тип ( тип page) на моем сайте https://t****n.ru/ с помощью post-запроса на мой сайт и соответствующего кода который указан у меня в файле functions.php моей темы.

Но запись в базе данных сайта не появляется (не вижу новую запись в phpmyadmin) до тех пор пока я не загружу юрл с созданной страницей в моем браузере или же когда я загружу в браузере в админке список страниц сайта ( этот url https://t*****n.ru/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&orderby=date&order=desc). И только тогда запись в БД сайта появляется!

Подскажите почему так? И где можно посмотреть логи происходящих процессов приводящих к отображению в phpmyadmin новой записи?

Comment: "соответствующего кода" -- это какого? Может имеет смысл его привести, чтоб можно было сказать, что с ним не так?

Comment: Тут надо спрашивать специалистов по уордпресс, которые понимают эту адову кухню. Мое предположение - что автор вопроса смотрит не то и не там не там. А "появляется" запись в какой-то кэширующей таблице.

Comment: @rusgeli 
вот код в functions.php (код большой и в стак не помещается) : https://pastebin.com/wPeHRxST

Comment: @MikhailEliseev, что возвращает `create_page()`? Попробуйте явно указать пользователя, от имени которого добавляется страница.

Comment: уже сам разобрался. Спасибо.